# How to save pseudopotential?

Tags: pseudopotentials

I aim to do a plane-wave calculation after computing pseudopotentials. There are many ways to build [pseudopotentials](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/what-are-the-types-of-pseudopotentials) and each of them have their set of parameters.

What is the relevant piece of information to save and its format for a plane-wave calculation?